# sum of time datatype in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table named tblAttendanceDailySummary and there is a field is in time datatype named timeAttendanceHour(like 09:44:25). I want to sum of this field due to end of the month.I mean one employee's one month working time need to calculate.How can i sum time datatype.

Comment: Have you tried [SUM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)?

Comment: Post your query man atleast...

Comment: I have tried with this code "SELECT   CAST(DATEADD(MILLISECOND,SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,0,CAST(ISNULL(timeAttendanceHour,'00:00:00') AS DATETIME))),0) AS TIME) FROM dbo.tblAttendanceDailySummary WHERE intEmployeeID = 1397 AND (dbo.tblAttendanceDailySummary.intMonthId =04) AND dbo.tblAttendanceDailySummary.intYear = 2012 "

Comment: @yeasir007: please **DO NOT** put code samples into comments - you cannot format it, it's really really hard to read for everyone. Instead: **update** your original question by **editing it!** and provide that extra information - thank you!

Comment: What is the problem with [the query you have](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67129)?

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson suppose if i manually calculate than 15 days working hour will be 120.30 hours(that means 14days per day 8 hours and another one is 8.30hours) but my query returns 00:30:00.0000000

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sql 2008 and this problem is solved now by Mikael Eriksson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time data type has a range of 00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999 so you can't cast to time. You have to calculate the hour, minute and second instead.

Something like this could work for you

```
select H.Val, M.Val, S.Val
from (
       --Your query goes here
       select dateadd(second, sum(datediff(second, 0, timeAttendanceHour)), 0) as sumtime
       from YourTable
     ) as T
  cross apply (select datedifF(hour, 0, T.sumTime)) as H(Val)
  cross apply (select datediff(minute, 0, dateadd(hour, -H.Val, T.sumTime))) as M(Val)
  cross apply (select datediff(second, 0, dateadd(hour, -H.Val, dateadd(minute, -M.Val, T.sumTime)))) as S(Val)
```

If you want the result as HH:MM:SS you can use this:

```
select cast(H.Val as varchar(10))+':'+right(M.Val+100, 2)+':'+right(S.Val+100, 2)
```

Comment: Hi @Mikael thank you.I want to get more help from you.Main purpose of this query is to calculate total salary of a worker whose salary per hour like 10$(as money datatype) and he/she works total 245.35 hours due to a month which return by this query. how can i multiple those i mean salary per hour and this query result.thank you.

Comment: @yeasir007 - `sum(datediff(second, 0, timeAttendanceHour)) / 3600.0` will give you the number of worked hours as a decimal.

Comment: Hi @Mikael thank you so much again.It's working and thanks again for for this nice post.God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

How about converting the components to a standard integer and summing them:

select sum(second(timeAttendanceHour))/60 + 
    sum(minute(timeAttendanceHour)) +
 
    sum(hour(timeAttendance))*60 as MonthlyMinutes, 
intMonthID
from tblAttendanceDailySummary
where intYear = 2012
group by intEmployeeID, intMonthID

Comment: This query throw error like" 'second' is not a recognized built-in function name."